# JSoup parse HTML div tag

Tags: html, tags, jsoup

By searching this site I've been able to get mostly all of my answers..Thanks for that!

Unfortunately I ran into a snag parsing a file with Football Stat data which is bugging me. The div tag below seems to have multiple nested elements which I just can't figure out how to parse. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

The div id is player_data, i got that and I basically want the data for the player like:

**8780,Matt,Ryan,Atl,2,Boston College,76.0....etc**

The div tag contains data for 2 players Matt Ryan and Aaron Rogers. The original file contains over 200 players using the same format below.

```
<div id="player_data" style="display: none;">
[{"player_id":8780,"position":"QB","first_name":
"Matt","last_name":"Ryan","team_alias":"Atl","number":"2","college":"Boston 
College","height":76.0,"weight":217.0,"age":27,"team_city":
"Atlanta","team_name":"Falcons","experience":6,"next_matchup":      [{"opponent":"Oak","game_datetime":"10/14, 1:00 

PM"}],"salary":18408,"injured":false,"pstats":
[{"year":10015,"yds":714,"paint":2,"td":5,"g":2},
{"year":2012,"yds":1507,"paint":3,"td":13,"g":5},
{"year":2011,"yds":4177,"paint":12,"td":29,"g":16}],"rstats":
[{"year":10015,"yds":4,"td":0},{"year":2012,"yds":52,"td":1},
{"year":2011,"yds":84,"td":2}],"recstats":[{"year":10015,"rec":0,"yds":0,"td":0},
{"year":2012,"rec":0,"yds":0,"td":0},{"year":2011,"rec":0,"yds":0,"td":0}],"fumstats":
[{"year":10015,"fl":1},{"year":2012,"fl":1},{"year":2011,"fl":3}],"exstats":
[{"year":10015,"twopts":0},{"year":2012,"twopts":0},{"year":2011,"twopts":0}],"dstats":[]},
{"player_id":7200,"position":"QB","first_name":"Aaron","last_name":"Rodgers","team_alias":"
GB","number":"12","college":"California","height":74.0,"weight":225.0,"age":28,"team_city":
"Green Bay","team_name":"Packers","experience":9,"next_matchup":
[{"opponent":"@Hou","game_datetime":"10/14, 8:20 
PM"}],"salary":17721,"injured":false,"pstats":
[{"year":10015,"yds":562,"paint":2,"td":7,"g":2},
{"year":2012,"yds":1307,"paint":4,"td":10,"g":5},
{"year":2011,"yds":4643,"paint":6,"td":45,"g":15}],"rstats":
[{"year":10015,"yds":70,"td":0},{"year":2012,"yds":108,"td":0},
{"year":2011,"yds":257,"td":3}],"recstats":[{"year":10015,"rec":0,"yds":0,"td":0},
{"year":2012,"rec":0,"yds":0,"td":0},{"year":2011,"rec":0,"yds":0,"td":0}],"fumstats"
:[{"year":2012,"fl":0},{"year":2011,"fl":0}],"exstats":[{"year":10015,"twopts":0},
{"year":2012,"twopts":0},{"year":2011,"twopts":0}],"dstats":[]}]}]</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Player data is in JSON format. You can parse it using Java JSON library, see Java JSON libraries [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338586/a-better-java-json-library). JSON in your example seems to be invalid (checked with [this validator](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)), so that might cause some trouble when parsing that JSON.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I will read up on JSON.